# Google or-tools soft constraint issue

Tags: python, optimization, or-tools

I would like to know how to add a soft constraint in the scenario below:

There a group with total 4 people and they are allowed to conduct 1 / 2 tasks, and the preference is 4 people in one task —> evenly split 2 teams (2 people per team) for 2 tasks —> 3 people for 1 task and the rest 1 for another task

How can I compose the soft constraint that if 2 out of 4 / all 4 are true, there will has no penalty, otherwise will do the penalty.

Thanks for your advise and instruction !!

Comment: you need to show some code and give some details. What solvers? Provide a prototype code with just a comment in place of the missing constraint.